# Special consideration to or for?

Tags: prepositions

Let's say you are one of the contestants in a contest, then the MC just remind you that:

> 'They won't make any special consideration **to/for** your case.''

Which is correct?

Comment: I would say "for", although I'd say "to" is acceptable too. I would actually use "give" instead of "make". If using "give" then "to" would be more appropriate. Sorry for confusing you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The preposition "to" implies an action happening to the object or something moving toward the object.  For example:

> We'll move to your case next

The action "move" needs a direction even if it's a philisophical direction and not a literal direction.  The direction in the above example is "to" (toward) your case.

- The preposition "for" means (among other things) "on behalf of" or "because of."  It implies an action happening for the benefit of or the detriment of the object.

> I'll clean my room for your sake.

In this example, the room will be cleaned, not because the occupant wants to clean it or should clean it, but on behalf of someone else (who apparently wants it cleaned, like a parent).

**Thus, in your example, you would use the preposition "for" because the consideration will be refused to the detriment of (on behalf of) your case or situation.**